# Is there a way to eliminate the 'TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query' error when updating a database using JPA hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

When I call and run this method from a java test class, I get a `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`error. What could I have done wrong? I dug online and found a popular suggestion to add @Transactional annotation to the method. Unfortunately, this action did not resolve my query.
I imported `import javax.transaction.Transactional;`

```
@Transactional
        public List<TestEntity> testUpdate() {
            return execute("punit", entityManager -> {
                Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("myDate").setMaxResults(20);
                LocalDateTime dayBefore = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1);
                query.setParameter("previousDate", Timestamp.valueOf(dayBefore)).executeUpdate();
                return query.getResultList();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

as form the configuration xml it is clear that you are going to use spring based transaction.

Please make sure that the import which you are using for `@Transactional` **`"org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional"`**

in your case it might be **`"javax.transaction.Transactional"`**

Simply try below code. It's working fine for me.

```
package com.sample;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class Sample {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public Optional<Model> updateRecord() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;`but it is not working. I hovered on Transaction and the error says Cannot resolve symbol 'transaction'

Comment: Where you are getting this error `Cannot resolve symbol 'transaction' `??

Comment: In `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; the word` transaction is in red and cannot be resolved

Comment: @Theman you should attach your Maven/Gradle dependency configuration to your Question. Looks like you are missing dependency on `spring-tx` artifact or other artifact that includes it. Or you just forgot to rerun the script (`mvn clean compile` or `gradlew build`)

Comment: Its a maven project. What's the required artefact?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: That artefact is not working for me. I must be missing something else